# Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation Angular 8 - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

> 42% building 274/275 modules 1 active
>   ...\src\index.js??extracted!D:\Clients\app\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js??ref--15-3!D:\src\styles.scss
>   <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [12996:000002DFC57D42F0]    43111 ms: Scavenge 1335.4 (1425.0) ->
>   1335.3 (1426.0) MB, 2.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.169, current mu = 0.100) allocation failure [12996:000002DFC57D42F0]    43489 ms: Mark-sweep 1336.2 (1426.0) -> 1335.4 (1425.5) MB, 375.8 / 0.0 ms 
>   (average mu = 0.144, current mu = 0.100) allocation failure scavenge
>   might not succeed
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> ```
> 0: ExitFrame [pc: 00000257D3FDC5C1] Security context: 0x00b77541e6e9 <JSObject>
> 1: createNode [000001A31ED4EFF1] [D:\Clients\app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~16489]
> ```
>
> [pc=00000257D55AD889](this=0x02b823cedf89 ,kind=275,pos=-=-1,end=-1)
>       2: createPropertyAssignment [000001A31ED54669] [D:\Clients\app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescri...
>
> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
>   failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  1: 00007FF76C26DD8A
>   v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506  2:
>   00007FF76C248886 node::MakeCallback+4534  3: 00007FF76C249200
>   node_module_register+2032  4: 00007FF76C5630DE
>   v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846  5: 00007FF76C56300F
>   v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639  6: 00007FF76C749804
>   v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620  7: 00007FF76C7407E6
>   v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24550  8: 00007FF76C73EE3C
>   v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17980  9: 00007FF76C747B87
>   v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327 10: 00007FF76C747C06
>   v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454 11: 00007FF76C871EA7
>   v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55 12: 00007FF76C8EF096
>   v8::internal::operator<<+73494 13: 00000257D3FDC5C1

I have tried this solution: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618#issuecomment-450151214

i.e.

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",// here
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build:prod": "ng build --configuration=prod",
    },
```

After that

> npm run ng-high-memory --build --prod

But it says

> ```
> > > metronic-angular@6.0.0 ng-high-memory D:\Clients\app
> > > node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
> > 
> > Available Commands:   add Adds support for an external library to your
> > project.   analytics Configures the gathering of Angular CLI usage
> > metrics. See https://v8.angular.io/cli/usage-analytics-gathering.  
> > build (b) Compiles an Angular app into an output directory named dist/
> > at the given output path. Must be executed from within a workspace
> > directory.   deploy (d) Invokes the deploy builder for a specified
> > project or for the default project in the workspace.   config
> > Retrieves or sets Angular configuration values in the angular.json
> > file for the workspace.   doc (d) Opens the official Angular
> > documentation (angular.io) in a browser, and searches for a given
> > keyword.   e2e (e) Builds and serves an Angular app, then runs
> > end-to-end tests using Protractor.   generate (g) Generates and/or
> > modifies files based on a schematic.   help Lists available commands
> > and their short descriptions.   lint (l) Runs linting tools on Angular
> > app code in a given project folder.   new (n) Creates a new workspace
> > and an initial Angular app.   run Runs an Architect target with an
> > optional custom builder configuration defined in your project.   serve
> > (s) Builds and serves your app, rebuilding on file changes.   test (t)
> > Runs unit tests in a project.   update Updates your application and
> > its dependencies. See https://update.angular.io/   version (v) Outputs
> > Angular CLI version.   xi18n Extracts i18n messages from source code.
> > 
> > For more detailed help run "ng [command name] --help"
> ```

So how can I run this command properly?

***Note:*** I use the latest Angular i.e. `"@angular/core": "^8.2.14"`, and `"@angular/cli": "^8.3.19"`,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This works for me on **November 2019**

I have updated to the latest Angular like so: `ng update @angular/cli@^8 @angular/core@^8`

Then

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
    "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration=prod",
}
```

After that:

```
npm run ng-high-memory
```

**Url:** [JavaScript heap out of memory](https://dev.to/koscheyscrag/fix-of-angular-cli-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error-while-running-ng-serve--1jjh)

Comment: It's not only in Angular 8. I'm facing this problem in Angular 5 too. I've add this command to my package.json and it's working fine. But I don't know if this approach is correct.

Comment: @jpcmf80 Yes, the above approach is the clean and right way. You can see the above thread and it confirmed by Google core team members.

Comment: @Sampath I'm able to build successfully using this command but it's not committing the code while executing the commit command . Facing following error:
"  FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Comment: @Sampath can you please help here...!

Comment: @NaseerAttari What is your issue?

Comment: @Sampath unable to  committing the code after build successfully with error :  " FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Comment: Did you do the above solution and many more on the link I have shared above? @NaseerAttari

Comment: for making build, i used the command you mentioned above, the build was made successfully, then i did git add successfully, but then it failed on commit. @Sampath

Comment: @NaseerAttari Then you need to open a new Question. This is only for the build.

Comment: I was facing this problem in github actions. I am using dockerfile for building image. I finally found where should I write the "node --max_old_space_size=8000" command. I wrote "RUN node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod" instead of "RUN ng build --prod"

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade the node js version to **v12** or a greater version than the one you are currently using.

Comment: it worked for me with installed `node -v` v12.16.1. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You are running out of memory allocated.

In your project directory, **run this command.**

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
```

*(This sets 8GB memory allocated).*

**Then,**

`ng serve --open` OR `ng build --prod`

**Or**
Use like this,

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 & ng serve --open
```

To avoid typing all these together every time we can save this script inside the **package.json** file.

Inside
**"scripts": {....}**

```
"scripts": {
    .....
    "mserve":"set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 & ng serve --open"
    }
```

**Then** in Terminal, inside your project. **Run**

```
npm run mserve
```

*You can rename mserve to anything you want*

Answer (score 4):

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192
```

`export` worked for me instead of `set`. And I ran this from the terminal in the parent directory that contained the test files.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following command on cmd rather than fixing the memory issue from package.json. And this worked for me.

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

I was using angular 6, and I didn't have to upgrade to the latest version of angular. This error is not related to the angular version I guess.

Answer (score 2):

It will solve after Increasing the node max memory size

```
// terminal
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096

// Windows
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
```

Answer (score 2):

It might look ridiculous but `!===` instead `!==` caused this issue in my case. So check your code for any typos.

Comment: Yes!!! I made "replace all" action on an .html file for "==" and replaced by "===", but it was "====" and "!===". Would never caught

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error, but in my case, the issue was related to the **angular.json** settings. It had to do with the "budget" setting.

It was originally like this...

```
 "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
```

After the fix...it looked like this...

```
    "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb"
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular.Json   Architect>build>options>      "aot": false,   Change aot false to Solve in Angular  this one Reason

Answer (score 0):

On my raspbarry pi model 3, the RAM (1GB) and swap space (1GB) was to small.
After increasing the swap space to 10GB, the suggested command "ng-high-memory" worked!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, how do you do that ? Thanks.

Comment: I used this article: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-add-swap-space-in-linux/.
Summary: remove original swapspace and create a bigger swapspace.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is those who does't want to increase the `heap size`
.
The solution is restart the dev server when it's down and constantly watch for every 30 seconds

```bash
while true
do
    if lsof -Pi :3000 -sTCP:LISTEN -t >/dev/null ; then
        echo "Port 3000 is open"
    else
        echo "Port 3000 is closed"
        echo "Restarting server"
        yarn start
    fi
    sleep 30
done
```